# Parser XML in QML Javascript getElementsByTagName error

Tags: javascript, xml, qt, qml, qt5

Why I can't get value from `tag=IMIE` to `nameTextField.text` in `QML` ?

```
Error: TypeError: Property 'getElementsByTagName' of object [object Object] is not a function
```

my function

```
function load()
{
    var xmlDoc;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.HEADERS_RECEIVED) {
            //console.log('HEADERS_RECEIVED')
        } else if(xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            xmlDoc=xhr.responseXML;

    //error
                    nameTextField.text = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("IMIE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue; // <- error: TypeError: Property 'getElementsByTagName' of object [object Object] is not a function
    //error

            }
        }
        //xhr.open("GET", "");
        //xhr.send();
    }
```

I find this in reported bug, but how I can work around this problem ?

Comment: Please link to the reported bug.

Comment: https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-19809